# Default taskScheduler Bean - Spring integraion 2.2.0 Vs 3.0.2 with Spring 3.2.9

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a stand alone application that uses File inbound channel adapter to poll for a file from a Specified location at certain interval.
I don't have a taskScheduler instance defined.
When running the application with both Spring integration 2.2.0 and 3.0.2, I see that there are 10 threads created with name task-scheduler-x after certain amount of time. I believe this is the default behavior.

I removed the file inbound channel adapter configuration from my application and re-run it, I noticed the following behavior.

In 3.0.2 , 10 threads are getting created with name task-scheduler-x. 
In 2.2.0, Though a taskScheduler instance is getting created (I can see the message about the bean creation in the logs), I don't see any threads getting created with the name task-scheduler-x.

Why is this behavior different between these two versions?  What should I do if I don't want to create a taskScheduler instance or I don't want to create any threads for task scheduling?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework now has a built-in component (header channel registry) that uses the `taskScheduler`.

It's not really using many resources although it does have this side effect of instantiating the scheduler thread pool.

We'll look at adding an option to disable it if you don't need/use it. In the meantime, you can revert to the pre 3.0 behavior by adding this bean to your context:

```
<bean id="integrationHeaderChannelRegistry" class="org.springframework.integration.channel.DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
</bean>
```

I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3545) for this.